# Ethereum full node size (default vs archive)

Tags: storage, full-node

I'm looking at etherscan right now and I have 2 questions.

There are 2 versions of full node sync chart, default and archive, what is the difference between them?

And why is it that in the FULL NODE SYNC (DEFAULT) CHART, the chan data size suddenly decreases drastically around 2022, 2023 Jan-Feb?

Here is the links:

https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault

https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chainarchive

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

> There are 2 versions of full node sync chart, default and archive,
> what is the difference between them?

A default full node keeps the most recent 128 block's state data while an archive node keeps all historical state data.
We have a blog post on this topic: [A dive into the full vs archive mode](https://chainstack.com/evm-nodes-a-dive-into-the-full-vs-archive-mode/), you may find it helpful.

> And why is it that in the FULL NODE SYNC (DEFAULT) CHART, the chan data size suddenly decreases drastically around 2022, 2023 Jan-Feb?

We need to note that this chart represents the Etherscan Geth node's size, not a general Ethereum node. On the chart itself, it is labeled that Data was pruned on Jan/26/2022. [Pruning](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/pruning) is a tactic to reduce the number of state snapshots in a node. I guess it happened again in 2023.

I hope it helps, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Highright on the right-hand side of the link you provided.

> Ethereum Full Nodes can be synched using different state pruning modes. On [Archive Settings] all previous states are retained and with the Default Settings older states are pruned.

The reason the full node's data decreasesed is because it was pruned.

What is pruning? -> https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/pruning